# Eclipse C++ Runs on Windows Command Prompt

Tags: c++, eclipse

I wrote a simple C++ code. When I click "Run" on Eclipse, first a Windows command prompt appears with my program. After executing it, Eclipse console starts to work. Is there a way to deactivate command prompt and just use Eclipse console?

```
   #include <iostream>


int main(){
    int x = 0,y = 0;
    std::cout <<"type2 numbers and I will make a magic trick."<< std::endl;

    std::cin >> x >> y;

    std::cout<<"Ta daa "<<x<<" and "<<y<<" equals to "<<x+y<<std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

When I erase std:cin part, command prompt appears and dissappears less than a second so I guess everytime I run my code, this command prompt will appear.

Comment: Try getch(); or stdd::cin.get(); .